# Azure DevOps Scheduled Release Issue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps release pipeline setup to release to my test environment at a scheduled time in the morning at 4am. The deployment queue setting is set to "Deploy latest and cancel the others".

We manually released #931 to test on 4/27 at 1pm. Release #929 never was never (manually) released to test on 4/27. On 4/28, release #929 was released to test at 4am (scheduled).

I don't want this behavior. I assumed that since #931 was released to test, #929 would be "cancelled" and not released to test. Is there a setting or modification to make this the actual behavior?

Below are some screenshots if they help:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Deploy latest and cancel the others" only applies to releases that are currently pending, not scheduled ones. The cancel is referring to the release itself, not the schedule.

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#specify-queuing-policies):

> Use this option if you are producing releases faster than builds, and you only want to deploy the latest build.

I've searched for simple ways to conditionally fire the schedule, but I wasn't able to find one. The way I work around it is have the schedule always create releases but have the tasks configured to only execute under certain conditions.

Comment: Interesting. What kind of conditions are you using on your tasks?

Comment: In my case, I want the release to only execute once a month (on Patch Tuesday). It has to run every Tuesday because DevOps doesn't have that option. When it runs, the first thing it does is execute a script that determines if this is the *correct* Tuesday, and if it is, sets a variable in the pipeline which I call `ExecuteStage` to True. Then the tasks are marked under Control Options to have this condition `and(succeeded(), eq(variables['ExecuteStage'], 'True'))`